# Create a simple parser

Tags: c, parsing

I have to develop a simple parser, to read "block" of text
for example:

```
/TEST
 {. text .}
/TEST_DATA
 {. infs .}
```

and, I need to read informations of inside of label....
and... the file with have this informations... have a lot of labels, with the same perfil

for example:

```
/TEST
 {. text .}
/TEST_DATA
 {. infs .}

/LBL1
 {. text .}
/LBL1_DATA
 {. infs .}

/LBL2
 {. text .}
/LBL2_DATA
 {. infs .}

/LBL3
 {. text .}
/LBL3_DATA
 {. infs .}
```

i need to read the block of specif label, for example:

parseFile("FileName.txt", LBL1)

and the function, return for me, the text of inside the blocks: LBL1 and LBL1_DATA
or, return for me, the content of LBL1 and LBL1_DATA

I don't know, how I can do this :xxx
I need help ;x

Thanks.

Comment: Can you use a scripting language, like awk, instead of c? What have you already tried?

Comment: Yes, I Tried, but, I don't know, how I can get the text of label :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming data in one-line, here's a very simple code example.

You need, obviously test it, test it and test it. Looking to your behavior, fixing possible bugs and something that I  forgot to do(it's a work for you now) and so do your new implementations.

```
int main(void)
{
    const char *key = "TEST";
    const char *filename = "file";

    char *val = get(filename, key);
    if(val) {
        printf("%s\n", val); // {. text .}
        free(val); // don't to forget!
    } else {
        printf("'%s' was not found.\n", key);
    }


}


char*
get(const char *filename, const char *key) {

    char *line = NULL, *pline = NULL, *buf = NULL, *pbuf, *tbuf;
    size_t size = -1, ssearch = strlen(key), i = 0, bufsize = 256;
    int open = 0;
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");

    if(fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot read '%s' file.\n", filename);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while(getline(&line, &size, fp) != -1) {

        if(open == 0 && *line == '/' && 
           strncmp(line + 1, key, ssearch) == 0 && isspace(((unsigned char)*(line + ssearch + 1)))) {
            open = 1;
            continue;
        }

        if(open) {
            pline = line;

            while(isspace((unsigned char) *pline)) ++ pline; /* strip white-spaces [\r\n\t\v ] */

            if(*pline == '{') {
                if((buf = malloc(bufsize)) == NULL) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "NO MEMORY!");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }

                ++pline; /* strip '{' */

                pbuf = buf;
                while(1) {

                    if(*pline == '\0') {
                        fprintf(stderr, "EOF but '{' was not closed.");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }

                    /* etc.. */

                    if(*pline == '}') break; 

                    if((i + size + 1) >= bufsize) {

                        if((tbuf = realloc(buf, bufsize + size + 1)) == NULL) {
                            if(buf) free(buf);
                            fprintf(stderr, "No MEMORY!\n");
                            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                        }

                        buf = tbuf;
                    }   

                    *pbuf ++= *pline++, 
                    i ++;
                }   

                *pbuf ++= '\0';

                if(pline != NULL) 
                    free(line);

                fclose(fp);

                return buf;

            } else {
                fprintf(stderr, "expected '{' but '%c' was found.\n", *pline);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }

        line = NULL;
        size = -1;
    }

    if(line != NULL)
        free(line);

    fclose(fp);


    return NULL;
}
```

**UPDATE:** a more simple code was written.

```
#define EXPECTEDSYMBOL(w, f) \
        fprintf(stderr, "expected '%c' but '%c' was found.\n", w, f); \
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE)

char* get2(const char *filename, const char *key) {

    char *line = NULL, *buf = NULL, *pline;
    size_t size = -1, ssearch = strlen(key);
    int open = 0;
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");

    if(fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot read '%s' file.\n", filename);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while(getline(&line, &size, fp) != -1) {

        if(open == 0 && *line == '/' && 
           strncmp(line + 1, key, ssearch) == 0 && isspace(((unsigned char)*(line + ssearch + 1)))) {
            open = 1;
            continue;
        }

        if(open) {

            pline = line;

            while(isspace((unsigned char) *pline)) ++ pline;

            if(*pline != '{') {
                EXPECTEDSYMBOL('{', *pline);
            } 

            if(strchr(pline, '}') == NULL) {
                EXPECTEDSYMBOL('}', *(pline + strlen(pline) - 1));
            }

            buf = pline;

            break;
        }

        line = NULL;
    }

    fclose(fp);


    return buf;

}
```

I hope this help you.

**EDIT #2:** I read again your question and seen that you need of  below key as well.

Try this:

```
void
get(const char *filename, const char *key, char buf[][512]) {

    char *line = NULL;
    size_t size = -1, ssearch = strlen(key);
    int open = 0;

    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");

    if(fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot read '%s' file.\n", filename);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while(getline(&line, &size, fp) != -1) {

        if(open == 0 && *line == '/' && 
           strncmp(line + 1, key, ssearch) == 0 && isspace(((unsigned char)*(line + ssearch + 1)))) {
            open = 1;
            continue;
        }

        if(open == 1) {
            strcpy(buf[0], line);
            ++ open;
            continue;
        }

        if((open + 1) == 3) {
            getline(&line, &size, fp);
            strcpy(buf[1], line);
            break;
        }
    }

    fclose(fp); 

}
```

And then:

```
const char *key = "TEST"; // /TEST
const char *filename = "config";
char buf[2][512] = { { 0 } };

get(filename, key, buf);
printf("%s\n", buf[0]); //  {. text . }
printf("%s\n", buf[1]); //  {. infs .}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have mainly two choices:

- parse the file manually, by storing everything in runtime structs and parsing the data by skipping tokens an parsing string (with aid of stdio, eg `fread`, `fscanf`, `fseek` and so on)
- using a parser generator (*flex + bison* are your first choice): you will need to study a little bit how these work but then everything will work like a charm, and it will be easily maintainable, take a look [here](http://www.scribd.com/doc/8669780/Lex-yacc-Tutorial) or [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/) for a quick start

Comment: flex and bison are gnu names for reimplementations of technologies which proceeded them, specifically lex and yacc. let's not get hung up on what RMS calls things between goes at his toejam http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I25UeVXrEHQ

Comment: Lex & Yacc are not freely available, Flex & Bison yes. So I don't see the point of pointing someone to software which is not readily available :)

Comment: I don't like them because they were born not as freeware, Flex & Bison are much more available without having to look any hidden variant (Last update of Bison? 5 June, are your "variants" updated as such?). But I read some rudeness in your comments. For a matter of naming? Did I offend you? Try to manage living with a community as your way is not a good way to do it.

Comment: "Not born as freeware" is, here, code for "not GPL"; some of us prefer free, not coercive, licenses. When was the last time there was a need to fix an issue with the BSD-licensed variants? "Update"s for the sake of having an update is pointless. ZOMG more recent commit! Pass the spoon! They are maintained, and used in production systems every day. Any real point you want to make?

Comment: Yes, the complete pointless opposition you are doing for a small issue, as if you developed yourself Lex & Yacc. I don't like them, place this information in your mind and live with it. Answering like a clown, like if SO allows trolling (because your way of answering can be considered trolling) is just a loss of time for both me and you. Anyone has his idead about licenses and whatever but you are the only one that wants to convince me to change my mind. You are allowed to use which one you like, just don't bother me.

Comment: And yet, here you are, answering me again, instead of not, which would have let my interest wane. Well done.

Comment: You interest should vane just because you are chasing windmills as Don Qhicotte. I guess users of this site should be enough old to avoid trolling like you seem to like. You should be able to understand by yourself when to stop annoying people.

Comment: But what if this has now taken on a life of its own, and I just want to see how long you'll keep responding? Will this then become something epic, an itch you can't help but scratch, when I speak out against coercive licenses and the devolution of understanding by the use of language designed not to inform what technology is, but a "trademark" implementation of said technology which involves poor puns?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use awk to process text.

```
$ awk '/^\/TEST$/, /}/{print $0}' test.dat | tail -1
 {. text .}
```

That tells awk to return a range of lines. The first line returned will match *this* regular expression, `^\/TEST$`; the last line returned will match *this* one, `}`. And `tail -1` passes only the last line to stdout.

If "text" can actually be many lines of text, then I'd probably pipe to awk instead of tail.

```
$ awk '/^\/TEST$/, /}/{print $0}' test.dat | awk 'NR!=1{print $0}'
 {. text
text
text
.}
```

You could repackage that one-liner as a shell script if you wanted to.